# Columns connection with an additional column

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have such columns in the database:

```
User
- int Id
- string Name

Flat
- int Id
- string Describe
```

The flat has a person who manages it and other residents

I think about this solution:

This is the relationship of ManyToMany with an additional column. In this column will be information if he is a managing person

```
UserFlat
- int UserId
- int FlatId
- bool Creator
```

Will this be the right approach?

How should I implement it exactly?

Is it directly as a ManyToMany relation or as a manually created and managed table?

The blockage is that users can belong to only one apartment (in the future, the manager will be able to belong to several apartments), but the remaining people can belong to only one apartment

Or is it a completely different and better solution?

Comment: ASP.NET Core is a web stack. It has nothing to do with databases and data access. Are you asking about *EF Core* perhaps?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, 2.0 or 2.1 but it is also about the concept

Comment: BTW the only way to create a many-to-many relation in a database is to create a many-to-many table. Your two options are actually the same option. Constraints like `only one tenant` or `one manager many flats` are handled by database constraints. Eg a UNIQUE costraint or Primary Key on `UserID` would ensure there's only one tenant per apartment.

Comment: BTW tables represent entities or relations. Tenant and Manager are *different* relations. You should probably use different tables for them. This would make adding the correct constraints a *lot* easier. Besides, can't a tenant be a manager of another apartment? Most likely you need Manager and Tenants as separate relations on the flat

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The manager may also be a resident of one of the apartments

Answer (score 1):

If a user can have only one flat and a flat can have only one manager, you don't need a separate table. This should suffice and will work even if one User can be manager of multiple flats:

```
    User
- int Id
- string Name
- int FlatId > FK to a Flat

Flat
- int Id
- string Describe
- int ManagerId > FK to a User
```

Comment: @Imposoft , yes, that is why the user has a FlatId, so many users can have the same one assigned.

Comment: Should I create two relationships? `OneToOne` (one User as Manager -> one Flat) and `OneToMany` (one Flat -> many Users) ?